# How can I safely rename a sequence in PostgreSQL, ideally without downtime?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, sequence, rename

We want to rename some sequences in our production database for [certain reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38666275/6962).

Is there a way to do this safely in production without having to first close all connections to the database?

It's fine if we get gaps in the ID sequence (e.g. it jumps from ID 123 to ID 200 or whatever) but we obviously don't want long locks causing delays/errors, don't want any risk of duplicate IDs and similar.

We're on PostgreSQL 9.5.21 on Heroku.

We've looked at [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-altersequence.html) but are still uncertain about the consequences of running

```
ALTER SEQUENCE old_id_seq RENAME TO new_id_seq;
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('new_id_seq');
```

in production. I guess one risk would be if stuff happens in `mytable` between those two commands. But what if we did something like this:

```
-- Starting at a much higher value than the currently highest ID.
CREATE SEQUENCE new_id_seq START 200;

ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('new_id_seq');

DROP SEQUENCE old_id_seq;
```

What are the risks of doing it that way?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Brilliant, thank you! Do you know if that is guaranteed to be atomic, in the sense that Weird Things Will Not Happen because things happen between the sequence rename and the automatic changing of the table's assigned sequence?

Comment: As the `ALTER SEQUENCE` acquires an exclusive lock, I would think yes, that's safe (again: **only** if the sequence is "owned" by the column)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are partly right. The changed name is reflected in the `DEFAULT` clause, but *not* because of the dependency to the column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If the sequence is used in the `DEFAULT` clause of the table column, it is enough to rename the sequence.

  That is because the `DEFAULT` clause is *not* stored as string, but as parsed expression tree (column `adbin` in catalog `pg_attrdef`). That expression tree does not contain the name of the sequence, but its object ID, which is unchanged by renaming the sequence. Tools like `psql`'s `\d` re-construct a string from the parsed expression, so the `DEFAULT` clause will appear to reflect the renaming.
- If the sequence name is used elsewhere, like in your client code or in a PostgreSQL function, you would have to change the name in that code. PostgreSQL functions are stored as strings (column `prosrc` in catalog `pg_proc`), so renaming a sequence can make a function that uses the sequence fail.

  In this case, you would have to suspend activity until you have changed the code and renamed the sequence if you want to avoid errors.

Comment: Ah, interesting. So my assumption, that the sequence must be owned by the column to make that work was wrong?

Comment: Yes. It's like with views: if you rename the base table, the new name is "magically" reflected in the view definition.

Comment: Thank you very much! Excellent info. Just to make sure I got it right: if we just rename the sequence, is that unproblematic in a running production system, assuming that string is not in any of our functions or app code? I.e. PG itself won’t throw errors, take long-running locks and such? I guess it uses that ID internally when it can, which could avoid most such issues.

Comment: Also, what more specifically is the issue with the second case, that would require suspending activity? That the ALTER TABLE will take an exclusive lock, and so would be problematic with a big table?

Comment: No; the second case is where you use the sequence name in your application code or a PostgreSQL function. If you rename the sequence, but don't change the code, the code will fail because it references a non-existing sequence. There is no way to synchronize `ALTER SEQUENCE ... RENAME` and `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` or deploying new application code short of suspending application activity between these actions.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. The second case in your answer, not the second code suggestion in my question :) Thank you again. So it sounds like we can safely just rename the sequence in our case, since we don't reference it in functions and don't reference it directly in our app code (unless our app framework does it, but we don't believe so).

Comment: Right. I have structured my answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the mentioned method is going to solve your problem. In both cases, PostgreSQL is going to acquire a lock on the table, and the application has to wait for the ALTER command to be finished.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE <sequence name> RENAME TO <new sequence name>
```

Above command should be fast and you don't need following

```
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN SET DEFAULT nextval('new_id_seq');
```

After renaming the sequence. PostgreSQL internally knows the name has been changed.

Comment: Thank you! So if I just rename the sequence without touching the table, it should just work and not cause issues like slow locks?

Comment: That's pretty much what I said in my answer. But you forget that a sequence can be used in other places than a `DEFAULT` clause.